# Python Pandas: Change type from float to float64 in a column which contains both numerical and string elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume the following `pandas` dataframe:

```
df = 
       Column1       Column2       Column3     Column4
       2007-01-02    1M            String1     String2 
       2007-01-02    1M            0.051695    0.0057984
       2007-01-02    1M            0.0498056   0.00725827
       2007-01-02    1M            0.0493161   0.00780772
       2007-01-02    1M            0.0492764   0.00810296
       2007-01-02    1M            0.0493988   0.00820139
       2007-01-02    1M            0.0495177   0.00829837
       2007-01-03    1M            String1     String2 
       2007-01-03    1M            0.0516506  0.00589057
       2007-01-03    1M            0.0496136  0.00726748
       2007-01-03    1M            0.0490747  0.00781708
       2007-01-03    1M            0.0490845   0.0081065
       2007-01-03    1M            0.0492069  0.00820219
       2007-01-04    1M            String1    String2     
       2007-01-04    1M            0.0510632  0.00589493
              ...    ...           ...        ...
```

Columns `Column3` and `Column4` are considered as objects. When I check the `type` of the second element of `Column3` (i.e. `0.051695`) I get `float`. My question is if I can change the numerical elements of `Column3` and `Column4` from `float` to `float64`. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
df[["Column3"]][df["Column3"]!="String1"] = 
df[["Column3"]][df["Column3"]!="String1"].astype(np.float64)
```

which gave me the error

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

```
df.loc[:,"Column3"][df["Column3"]!="String1"] = 
df.loc[:,"Column3"][df["Column3"]!="String1"].astype(np.float64)
```

which gave me the error

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is possible change with pass mask to `loc` function:

```
mask = df["Column3"]!="String1"
df.loc[mask,"Column3"] = df.loc[mask,"Column3"].astype(np.float64)
```

Another idea if convert all possible numeric, non numeric generate missing values, so replaced by original:

```
df['Column3'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Column3'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['Column3'])
```

For test is posible use checking `type`:

```
print (df['Column3'].apply(type))
0       <class 'str'>
1     <class 'float'>
2     <class 'float'>
3     <class 'float'>
4     <class 'float'>
5     <class 'float'>
6     <class 'float'>
7       <class 'str'>
8     <class 'float'>
9     <class 'float'>
10    <class 'float'>
11    <class 'float'>
12    <class 'float'>
13      <class 'str'>
14    <class 'float'>
Name: Column3, dtype: object
```

In my opinion still best should be only numeric column with missing values for non match values:

```
df['Column3'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Column3'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: The mask solution doesn't seem to work in my example but the third suggestion seems like an option. Thanks.